# How to get ortho image url on dronedeploy for a plan

Tags: dronedeploy

Is there a way to get URL of an ortho image using dronedeploy api? I can see that Image.get can give me image or an array of the images?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to just get a single geotiff or a specific tile?

Comment: I am looking to get a single / stitched geotiff image

Answer (score 0):

The best way to retrieve and ortho via the API currently is through the Export API. This will require either a webserver, or an email scraper since the export link will be sent to email and/or webhook.

Additionally, you can list existing exports and if the user has already generated an ortho, either use the first ortho you find, or present a list to the user to select. Then use the download link in the ortho object to retrieve it.

- Experience: I am an engineer at DroneDeploy!